# Как убрать уголок у textarea не используя resize: none?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, resize

Нужно убрать уголок у textarea так, чтобы осталось свойство resize (оно нужно для выполнения скрипта).

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ - вот это можете попробовать

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант обернуть `textarea`.

```css
div {  
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
</div>
```

Пользователь не сможет менять размеры, а скриптом можно.
Есть маленький недочет в таков случае: в углу где скрыт уголок не меняется курсор.